# Language customizatio- Custom Policy - Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Am trying to configure language customization for sign up using custom policies, but with no success. Any guidance appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
 I made the following configuration to achieve language customization.
```

1. In trust framework extension policy, I have enabled localization with following XML changes.

   ```
       <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" >
         <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
         <SupportedLanguage>fr</SupportedLanguage>
         <SupportedLanguage>ta</SupportedLanguage>
       </SupportedLanguages>
   ```
2. Created Localization resource for claim type  'extension_CompanyName'.

   ```
     <LocalizedResources Id="api.idpselections.signup.fr">
         <LocalizedStrings>

           <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_CompanyName" StringId="DisplayName"> Some French word</LocalizedString>
           <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_CompanyName" StringId="UserHelpText">Some french text</LocalizedString>
         </LocalizedStrings>
       </LocalizedResources>
   ```
3. Mapped the localized resource created in step 2 with sign up screen.

   ```
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections.signup" >
         <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
         <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
         <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:idpselection:1.0.0</DataUri>
         <Metadata>
           <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
           <Item Key="language.intro">Sign up</Item>
         </Metadata>
           <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
           <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup.en" />
           <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="fr" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup.fr" />
         </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
    </ContentDefinition>
   ```

Finally, in my SPA app while routing to sign up policy I have appened the new query parameter 'ui_locales = 'fr'. But, unfortunately, 'extension_CompanyName' is not showing localized text.

Correct me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Renaming localized resources id fixed my problem. Not sure how it worked.

```
 <ContentDefinitions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections.signup" >
    <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:idpselection:1.0.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
      <Item Key="language.intro">Sign up</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="en" />
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="fr" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="fr" />
    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
  </ContentDefinition>

  <LocalizedResources Id="fr">
          <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_CompanyName" StringId="DisplayName">Nom de la compagnie</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_CompanyName" StringId="UserHelpText">Nom de la compagnie</LocalizedString>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimsProvider" StringId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange">Local Account Sign-Up</LocalizedString>
          </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
```